# aHelp with a strange code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I' developing a webform that connects via https to a asmx. Is a third party webservice and they sent me the "code to connect" But it gives me errors at design time. I have successfully added the web reference and importing the namespace makes the services available (at design time) but there are other problems that prevent me to run it.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="XXX.FachadaCotizador" %>

<script runat="server">
   Private Const URIROOT As String = "https://ws.XXX.com.uy/TestCotizadoresBlock/fachadacotizador.asmx"

   Public Function Consultar(ByVal requestXml As String) As String Implements iHelper.Consultar

       Dim proxy As New WebReferenceHTTPS.FachadaConsulta
       Dim myCache As New CredentialCache


       myCache.Add(New Uri(URIROOT), "Negotiate", New NetworkCredential("UID", "PASS", "DOMAIN"))
      proxy.Credentials = myCache
       Dim emitir = proxy.Consultar("<Request><Entity>Catalogo</Entity><Params><Param >Name='cod_usuario' Value= 'PRUEBA' /><Param Name='cod_consulta' Value='MARCA' /><Param >Name='cod_subramo' Value='1' /></Params></Request>")
       MsgBox(emitir)



   End Function
```

The 2 errors i got are

-iHelper is not defined
-WebReferenceHTTPS.FachadaConsulta is not defined

I'm obviously missing an implementation or something on the flavor but googling didn't get me anywhere what do I have to do? How do I find those namespaces?

Comment: I think you need more Imports for those namespaces, similar to what you've done above for `FachadaCotizador`.

Comment: Yeah the same I think but I don't know witch namespaces are...

Comment: Ask the third party for the URL of their web service which may contain what you are missing.